# Can we define the length of a line segment in terms of addition of infinite points?

Tags: real-analysis

Since a point has zero length, how can a line segment of, say, 1-unit length—which is a collection (addition) of infinite points, that is $0 + 0 + \cdots$—have 1-unit length? Does it make sense to say $0 + 0 + \cdots = 0$?

Comment: It depends on how you define "length." (cf. [measure theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)) )

Comment: There are *uncountably* infinitely many points in the continuum.

Comment: If  $r_x = length(x) = 0$, it *might* or might not make sense to say $\sum\limits_{x\in [0,1]} r_x = 1$ but in *doesn't* make sense to say $\underbrace{r_{x_\alpha} + r_{x_\beta} +... }_{\text{for every }x_\gamma \in [0,1]}$ because there are *un*countable many such $x_\gamma \in [0,1]$ so we *CAN'T* list them one after another to add them.  That that's the *key* to measure theory.  A countable collection of things that have no length cant have any measure but an *un*countable collection of things with have no length *can*.

Answer (score 5):

Lebesgue measure is countably additive, but not additive over sets larger than countable ones.  As there are uncountably many points in the interval, this is not a problem.